# Not able to read scandinavian charater

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to parse a xml but since xml has scandinavian charaters such å,æ.
but getting these characters as jibberish.

I tried various thing:-

Try1)

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

Try2)

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(body));
        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
```

Try 3)

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource src = new InputSource();
src.setEncoding("UTF-8");
src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(body));
        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Ver");
        if (n1.getLength() > 0) {
            Ver = n1.item(0).getTextContent();
            if(Ver == "") {
                Ver = default1;
            }
            else {
                Ver = "\""+Ver+"\"";
            }
        }
```

XML Example:-

```
<?xml Version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Envelope>
    <Ver>Utåø</Ver>
    <ID>SAO</ID>
    <Rec>men</Rec>
    <TransactionID>0987714805168</TransactionID>
  </Envelope>
  <Code>124</Code>
  <City></City>
  <CompCodes>
    <CompCode>US</CompCode>
    <Vend>13</Vend>
  </CompCodes>
  <BankData>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <BankAcctNum>231</BankAcctNum>
  </BankData>
  <BankData>
    <Code>124</Code>
    <BankAcctNum>431</BankAcctNum>
  </BankData>
</Data>
```

Please let me know how to handle it.

Comment: What exactly is body in your examples? It seems this is a string with the XML content. But you didn't show us the code where you actually read the XML file.

Answer (score 3):

Your xml file is encoded in utf-8: `<?xml Version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

If you try to use the `utf-8` encoding that should work instead of `ISO-8859-1` for the parsing.

Comment: You can parse correctly the document but the scandinavian characters are jibberish?

Comment: Hi, I am parsing a xml and converting it into json.
in this process,at the output json 'Utå' is becoming 'UtÃ¥'.

Comment: the thing is that the parsing is fine, it takes your utf-8 encoded values, but in your document it encodes them in `ISO-8859-1`, you could try to either do a `new String(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))`, either change the output encoding with the internal java classes... or the best probably if you can is to use: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. please look at Try 3), it is encoding using utf-8.